# Automatically rename a file if it already exists in Windows way

Tags: c#, .net

My C# code is generating several text files based on input and saving those in a folder. Also, I am assuming that the name of the text file will be same as input. (The input contains only letters)
If two files has same name then it is simply overwriting the previous file.
But I want to keep both files.

I don't want to append current date time or a random number to the 2nd file name. Instead I want to do it the same way Windows does. If the first file name is `AAA.txt` then second file name is `AAA(2).txt`, third file name will be `AAA(3).txt` and .....N th file name will be `AAA(N).txt`.

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)
    .Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)).ToArray();

foreach (var item in allFiles)
{
    // newFileName is the txt file which is going to be saved in the provided folder
    if (newFileName.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // What to do here ?                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This will check for the existence of files with tempFileName and increment the number by one until it finds a name that does not exist in the directory.

```
int count = 1;

string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
string newFullPath = fullPath;

while(File.Exists(newFullPath)) 
{
    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
    newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
}
```

Comment: File-extensions would come out wrong, ex **C:\file.txt** would become **C:\file.txt(1)**" etc.

Comment: @flindeberg good catch.  I believe I have corrected this error.

Comment: For future ref. a little catch to be aware of: if the file that is being checked is named like `some name (1) some more text.txt` and the file already exist, if asked to keep both files Windows will rename the file `some name (2) some more text.txt`  and not `some name (1) some more text (1).txt` as the code above would instead do.

Comment: So this functionality isn't built into .NET?

Comment: How can we implement this in Java? Do you have any reference?

Answer (score 25):

With this code if file name is "Test (3).txt" then it will become "Test (4).txt".

```
public static string GetUniqueFilePath(string filePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        int number = 1;

        Match regex = Regex.Match(fileName, @"^(.+) \((\d+)\)$");

        if (regex.Success)
        {
            fileName = regex.Groups[1].Value;
            number = int.Parse(regex.Groups[2].Value);
        }

        do
        {
            number++;
            string newFileName = $"{fileName} ({number}){fileExtension}";
            filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, newFileName);
        }
        while (File.Exists(filePath));
    }

    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: What does this rename "some name (1) some more text.txt" to? it seems it would rename it to "some name (2).txt", which is very wrong.

Comment: @ANeves If "some name (1) some more text.txt" file exists then returns "some name (1) some more text (2).txt" file name.

Answer (score 9):

The other examples don't take into account the filename / extension.

Here you go:

```
    public static string GetUniqueFilename(string fullPath)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(fullPath))
            fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath);
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            String filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
            String path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.Length - filename.Length);
            String filenameWOExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
            String ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
            int n = 1;
            do
            {
                fullPath = Path.Combine(path, String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}", filenameWOExt, (n++), ext));
            }
            while (File.Exists(fullPath));
        }
        return fullPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
int count = 1;
String tempFileName = newFileName;

foreach (var item in allFiles)
{
  if (tempFileName.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    tempFileName = String.Format("{0}({1})", newFileName, count++);
  }
}
```

This will use the original file name if it's not there, if not it'll take a new file name with the index in brackets (although this code isn't taking the extension into account). If the newly generated name "text(001)" is used then it'll increment until it finds a valid unused file name.

Comment: You need to increment count.  Also, `tempFileName` is not re-checked against previous items.  Thus `tempFileName` could be changed to a item that has already been checked and pass.

Comment: @cadrell0: oops thanks... that was the plan! Typing too quickly.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the file extension. I've posted a different example below.

Comment: @Phill: No it doesn't... I did state that in the example. I'm providing an approach not the exact coded answer.

Comment: Apologies, I missed your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count= 0;
```

file is the name of file

```
while (File.Exists(fullpathwithfilename))  //this will check for existence of file
{ 
// below line names new file from file.xls to file1.xls   
fullpathwithfilename= fullpathwithfilename.Replace("file.xls", "file"+count+".xls"); 

count++;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `tempno` from?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string AutoRenameFilename(FileInfo file)
    {
        var filename = file.Name.Replace(file.Extension, string.Empty);
        var dir = file.Directory.FullName;
        var ext = file.Extension;

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string added;

            do
            {
                count++;
                added = "(" + count + ")";
            } while (File.Exists(dir + "\\" + filename + " " + added + ext));

            filename += " " + added;
        }

        return (dir + filename + ext);
    }
```

Comment: While this may provide a solution to the question, it would be better if you could provide some elaboration or explanation on how your code works, or any strengths/flaws it may have, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution that would move a file, and make sure that if the destination file name is not already taken. It would follow the same logic as Windows and append a number, with brackets after the duplicate file.

The top answer, thanks to @cadrell0, helped me arrive to the following solution:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates full file path for a file that is to be moved to a destinationFolderDir. 
    /// 
    /// This method takes into account the possiblity of the file already existing, 
    /// and will append number surrounded with brackets to the file name.
    /// 
    /// E.g. if D:\DestinationDir contains file name file.txt,
    /// and your fileToMoveFullPath is D:\Source\file.txt, the generated path will be D:\DestinationDir\file(1).txt
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="destinationFolderDir">E.g. D:\DestinationDir </param>
    /// <param name="fileToMoveFullPath">D:\Source\file.txt</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetFullFilePathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind(string destinationFolderDir, string fileToMoveFullPath)
    {
        string destinationPathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind;

        string fileNameWithExtension = Path.GetFileName(fileToMoveFullPath);
        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToMoveFullPath);
        string fileNameExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileToMoveFullPath);

        destinationPathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind = Path.Combine(destinationFolderDir, fileNameWithExtension);

        int count = 0;
        while (File.Exists(destinationPathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind))
        {
            destinationPathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind = Path.Combine(destinationFolderDir, $"{fileNameWithoutExtension}({count}){fileNameExtension}");
            count = count + 1; // sorry, not a fan of the ++ operator.
        }

        return destinationPathWithDuplicatesTakenInMind;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With regard to Giuseppe's comment on the way windows renames files I worked on a version that finds any existing index i.e. (2) in the file name and renames the file as per windows accordingly. The sourceFileName is assumed to be valid and the user is assumed to have write permission on the destination folder by this point:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    private void RenameDiskFileToMSUnique(string sourceFileName)
    {
        string destFileName = "";
        long n = 1;
        // ensure the full path is qualified
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(sourceFileName)) { sourceFileName = Path.GetFullPath(sourceFileName); }

        string filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFileName);
        string fileNameWOExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFileName);
        string fileNameSuffix = "";
        string fileNameExt = Path.GetExtension(sourceFileName);
        // if the name includes the text "(0-9)" then we have a filename, instance number and suffix  
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\(\d+\)");
        Match match = r.Match(fileNameWOExt);
        if (match.Success) // the pattern (0-9) was found
        {
            // text after the match
            if (fileNameWOExt.Length > match.Index + match.Length) // remove the format and create the suffix
            {
                fileNameSuffix = fileNameWOExt.Substring(match.Index + match.Length, fileNameWOExt.Length - (match.Index + match.Length));
                fileNameWOExt = fileNameWOExt.Substring(0, match.Index);
            }
            else // remove the format at the end
            {
                fileNameWOExt = fileNameWOExt.Substring(0, fileNameWOExt.Length - match.Length);
            }
            // increment the numeric in the name
            n = Convert.ToInt64(match.Value.Substring(1, match.Length - 2)) + 1;
        }
        // format variation: indexed text retains the original layout, new suffixed text inserts a space!
        do
        {
            if (match.Success) // the text was already indexed
            {
                if (fileNameSuffix.Length > 0)
                {
                    destFileName = Path.Combine(filepath, String.Format("{0}({1}){2}{3}", fileNameWOExt, (n++), fileNameSuffix, fileNameExt));
                }
                else
                {
                    destFileName = Path.Combine(filepath, String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", fileNameWOExt, (n++), fileNameExt));
                }
            }
            else // we are adding a new index
            {
                destFileName = Path.Combine(filepath, String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}", fileNameWOExt, (n++), fileNameExt));
            }
        }
        while (File.Exists(destFileName));

        File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `Dictionary<string,int>` to keep the number of times each root file name was saved. After that, on your `Save` method, just increase the counter and append it to the base file name:

```
var key = fileName.ToLower();
string newFileName;
if(!_dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    newFileName = fileName;
    _dictionary.Add(key,0);
}
else
{
    _dictionary[key]++;
   newFileName = String.Format("{0}({1})", fileName, _dictionary[key])
}
```

This way, you'll have a counter for each distinct file name: AAA(1), AAA(2); BBB(1)...

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now. thanks guys for the answers..

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)).ToArray();
        string tempFileName = fileName;
        int count = 1;
        while (allFiles.Contains(tempFileName ))
        {
            tempFileName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", fileName, count++); 
        }

        output = Path.Combine(folderPath, tempFileName );
        string fullPath=output + ".xml";
```