# Its about the copying image files from one directory to another

Tags: c#

I have 3 directories. These are images,good, bad. I'm getting images from images directory and I'm sending it the other directories. My question is, if good or bad directory have these images how can I change the name of images such as "I have car.jpg and if i copy it again , its name changes to car(1).jpg. I hope you understand my question..

Comment: Just check if the file already exists, if it does rename, can you show your code where it fails.

Comment: To check if a file already exists, use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) (who'd thunk...). If it does, use a loop with an incrementing `count` variable and check if `file(count).ext` exists. Play around a bit with [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx), [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) and [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13049909/2256349) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use code like this

```
internal static partial class IOUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Move a file to an archive folder
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Renames file if necessary to avoid collision.
    /// See <see cref="File.Move"/> for exceptions</remarks>
    /// <param name="file">path to file to move</param>
    /// <param name="targetFolder">folder to move file to</param>
    public static void ArchiveFile(string file, string targetFolder) {
        if (file == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
        if (targetFolder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("targetFolder");

        string targetFilename = Path.Combine(targetFolder, Path.GetFileName(file));
        File.Move(file, FindAvailableFilename(targetFilename));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Archive file in the same folder
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Renames file by adding first free "(n)" suffix
    /// See <see cref="File.Move"/> for exceptions</remarks>
    /// <param name="file">path to file to archive</param>
    public static void ArchiveFile(string file) {
        if (file == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");

        File.Move(file, FindAvailableFilename(file));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find a "free" filename by adding (2),(3)...
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetFilename">Complete path to target filename</param>
    /// <returns>First available filename</returns>
    private static string FindAvailableFilename(string targetFilename) {
        if (!File.Exists(targetFilename))
            return targetFilename;

        string filenameFormat = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(targetFilename) + "({0})" + Path.GetExtension(targetFilename);
        string format = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFilename), filenameFormat);
        for (int ii = 2;; ++ii) {
            // until we find a filename that doesn't exist
            string newFilename = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, ii);
            if (!File.Exists(newFilename)) // returns false on illegal paths, security problems etc
                return newFilename;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the sample code here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/212217/increment-filename-if-file-exists-using-csharp