# Rename existing file name

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have the following code which copies a file to a specific folder and then renames it.
When a file with that name already exists I get the following exception:

```
Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Is there a way to overwrite the file and rename it? or I should delete the old one and then change the name?

Here is my code:

```
 File.Copy(FileLocation, NewFileLocation, true);
 //Rename:
 File.Move(Path.Combine(NewFileLocation, fileName), Path.Combine(NewFileLocation, "File.txt"));
```

Comment: Why do you need to delete the old one?  Move should rename it "in place".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: As Jeff said, why delete it? Why not rename it or give your new file an incremental name? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049732/automatically-rename-a-file-if-it-already-exists-in-windows-way

Comment: @PaulZahra I think he means delete any existing file but it's not clear from the post.

Comment: Please don't edit your code to have your answer, it was confusing enough without that, but now it looks like you've asked a question and the question already contains the answer, even more confusing! When putting your answer into your question at least mark it as an edit.

Comment: I need to have in that folder only one file with a specific name. (It is a license file which must has a specific name.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to use only:

```
if (File.Exists("newfilename"))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete("newfilename");
}

System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

Comment: It doesn't help- It fails with exception when trying to move a file to a folder where there is a file with the same name.

Comment: indeed, this is same as OP's attempt.

Comment: you don't need use the File.Copy before.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob: If file already exists, you'll receive `IOException` (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 8):

One simple option is to delete the file if it exists:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(newFile)) System.IO.File.Delete(newFile);
System.IO.File.Move(oldFile, newFile);
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 6):

You're correct, [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw an `IOException` if/when the filename already exists. So, to overcome that you can perform a quick check before the move. e.g.

```
if (File.Exists(destinationFilename))
{
    File.Delete(destinationFilename);
}
File.Move(sourceFilename, destinationFilename);
```

Comment: Of course, based on the use case there's nothing that guarantees that there isn't a destination file there by the time you get to the move.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than letting the Exception throw.  You can then handle if the file should be overwrote or renamed.

Comment: But don't then assume it's going to succeed. Checking a priori is an optimization but not good control.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :** as a first step identify wether the file exists or not before copying the file.
using `File.Exists()` method

**Step 2:** if the file already exists with same name then delete the existing file using `File.Delete()` method

**Step 3:** now copy the File into the new Location using `File.Copy()` method.

**Step 4:** Rename the newly copied file.

Try This:

```
string NewFilePath = Path.Combine(NewFileLocation, fileName);
if(File.Exists(NewFilePath))
{ 
File.Delete(NewFilePath);
}

//Now copy the file first
File.Copy(FileLocation, NewFileLocation, true);

//Now Rename the File
File.Move(NewFilePath, Path.Combine(NewFileLocation, "File.txt"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I always use [MoveFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) with the flag **MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING**.

Limitations:

1. It needs to use PInvoke, so it means your code will only work on the Windows platform.
2. This flag MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING only work with File(Doesn't work with Folder)

> If lpNewFileName or lpExistingFileName name a directory and lpExistingFileName exists, an error is reported.