# how not to overwrite in FileUpload in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

in the code below

```
  public class UploadController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
          var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
           if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var docfiles = new List<string>();
                 foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName;
                    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    var nameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                    var i = 1;
                    while (File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
                    {
                        fileName = nameWithoutExtension.Trim() + " (" + i + ")" + extension;
                        i++;
                    }
                    docfiles.Add(filePath + fileName);
                   // docfiles.Add(filePath);
                }
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
            }
            else
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
             return result;
        }

    }
```

I really want to make a file upload the classic filename(1).jpg if file name is already exists but the code I had still delete the old files that has the same name, I don't know where I got it wrong i used while loop but it wasnt working

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing it the code below is working now it turns out i constructed it wrong :)

```
  var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" );
                         var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

                        var fileName = postedFile.FileName;
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        var nameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                        var i = 1;
                        while (File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
                        {
                            fileName = nameWithoutExtension.Trim() + " (" + i + ")" + extension;
                            i++;
                        }
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath + fileName);
```

Comment: The while loop should work, as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049909/6741868) also uses that method, try to follow exactly what it says, and please give more details than "*i used while loop but it wasnt working*" if it doesn't work ;)